# rails 3.0.3 - why are there so many sessions created without user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, nginx

On my rails 3.0.3, I see sessions created every few seconds, without a user id.

rails 3.0.3 nginx with passenger

I have cleaned the sessions with db:session:clean and new sessions continue to be created.

Why are so many sessions created?

Comment: people are hitting your site without loggin in, perhaps?

Comment: alredy see that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159571/why-does-ruby-on-rails-create-new-sessions-on-every-hit-sometimes?rq=1

Comment: If someone visits the site without login, I see "guest user".  So, still wondering...